# How do I Push from Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I have a project I want to push to github.

2 months ago I created a repository (as far as I remember this was done from the web interface)
https://github.com/Milliways2/QuollEyeTree

I now want to Push the latest source, and have added the repository to Xcode 5.0.2 in Preferences, using the address, adding my Username and Password.

When I go to `Source Control` `Push` Xcode tells me "no remotes found"

Comment: Sounds more like a configuration issue than an Xcode issue. Maybe something here will help: http://www.cimgf.com/2013/12/10/using-git-in-xcode/

Comment: This link refers to Xcode4 there is no "Repository" in Xcode5, but it started me on the right track.

Comment: My advice: forget Xcode's source control integration and use SourceTree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found where to set the repository
`Source Control/Working Copies (my Project)/Configure/Remotes`